# How to properly disable buttons temporarily in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am fairly new to WPF and still looking for an easy solution to temporarily deactivate the buttons in my application. Here is what I am doing:

Button Click:

```
private void Calculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      this.AreButtonsEnabled = false;
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
      this.AreButtonsEnabled = true;      
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="OtherButton" IsEnabled="{Binding AreButtonsEnabled}" Content="OtherButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="165,152,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
```

The binding works as expected, but if I activate and deactivate the buttons in this one call, the deactivation is not done. How do I get the GUI to properly deactivate the buttons?

**EDIT**

The notification event (that works fine):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
  {

    private bool areButtonsEnabled;
    public bool AreButtonsEnabled
    {
      get { return this.areButtonsEnabled; }
      set { areButtonsEnabled = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AreButtonsEnabled")); }
    }
```

**Note**
I am bound to .Net 3.5.

Comment: Could you post how your "AreButtonsEnabled" property is declared?

Comment: It's probably because the UI doesn't have time to react to the setting of `AreButtonsEnabled` to false before it sleeps.

Comment: I recommend using the ICommand interface with an basic implemenation like RelayCommand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be better to disable the buttons and then start/use another thread to do the work and enable the buttons at the end (one way to do that in one method is by using async/await) that way the UI will remain responsible and up to date.

Pseudo code:

```
private async void Calculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AreButtonsEnabled = false;
    await Task.Run(()=>DoWork());
    AreButtonsEnabled = true;      
}
```

Comment: [StartNew is Dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). Better use `Task.Run()`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am bound to the net framework 3.5.  But I get the idea. I think starting a new task would be an option, especially for time-consuming tasks. However I thought there might be a solution for tasks, that are not as extensive where it would be acceptable for the user to have a blocked gui (time span 1 - 2 seconds)?

Comment: @Kroetenwurz - Microsoft considers anything blocking the UI for over 50 ms to be 'bad'. Also, your scenario does require the UI to be updated (that was your original question) and at the same time the code is claiming the UI thread to do the work.

Comment: Ok, you convinced me. Thank you for your answers and input, both Erno and Clemens and the others. I'll let perform all tasks in non-UI threads.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.Sleep()` blocks the UI thread. You may use an `async` Click handler with `Task.Delay()` instead:

```
private async void Calculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AreButtonsEnabled = false;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    AreButtonsEnabled = true;      
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am bound to the net framework 3.5. But I get the idea. Can I force the GUI to update before entering the task (sleep)?

Comment: You must not call `Thread.Sleep` in the UI. Never. Instead, you may have some asynchronous operation, e.g. in a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Hey Clemens. The Sleep is a placeholder for a task that takes just one or two seconds. Enough for the user to press another button, something I'd like to prevent